# Is Parse relations/ pointers bi-directional?

Tags: android, mongodb, pointers, parse-platform, database

This code sets up a Customer class, creates an object in it and assigns a pointer connecting the customer object to the ParseUser who created it.

```
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser(); 

customer.put("CreatedBy", currentuser);
customer.saveInBackground;

ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Customer");
query.whereEqualTo("CreatedBy", currentUser); 
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>()
```

The pointer is defined from Customer --> User but the query is against the customers. To go to the user I just need to check the value in the createdBy column but for the reverse an entire query is needed. Do I need to define a pointer in the other direction to optimize the query/ speed it up or does Parse enforce bidirectionality in its pointers and relations?

In a MongoDB afaik pointers must be defined in both directions for optimum query speeds. I will be using customer class much more and my app should work for 100k users+
My same doubt applies to the case of ParseRelations. I know I can use the 'include' key but is query both ways equally optimized?

Comment: My experience is that creating pointers in both directions causes problems as a cyclic dependency is created. This is especially evident when enabling local datastore, as it recursively saves objects, which can act strange if cyclic dependencies is present. I found a question at the parse.com help page at some point where Hector mentioned something similar, but do not have the reference atm. The conclusion for me was to settle with having pointers in one direction.